# jquery-ui datepicker this.element.uniqueId is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, yarnpkg

I am trying to use jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker, but I get the error "this.element.uniqueId is not a function" caused from jquery-ui/ui/widgets/dialog.js:401:

`""aria-describedby": this.element.uniqueId().attr( "id" )".`

I am using jquery > 1.9, so the uniqueId() function should be there according to the documentation.
I have already tried different jQuery and jQueryUI versions, but the error still remains.

I am using jquery 3.4.1 and jquery-ui 1.12.1.

What's causing the issue here and how to fix it?

Edit:
This is my src/index.js

```js
window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");

var ui = require('jquery-ui');
$.ui = ui;

require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/dialog');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/tabs');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker');
```

And in my layout file I have included the built app.js and try the following code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#date-picker").datepicker();

    $("#box-tabs, #box-left-tabs").tabs();

});
```

When I remove the require of the datepicker the error does not come.

Comment: Have you tried something like `$(this).uniqueId();`

Comment: show us your code for this

Comment: When I try $(elem).uniqueId() it says it's not a function. And I can't alter the dialog.js file since the package must be the same on every development machine.